# O que vem depois de POO?

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, orientação-a-objetos, aplicação-desktop

Estou terminando o curso de POO em Java e gostaria de tirar um duvida.

Até agora não me foi passado nada em relação a como eu poderia colocar um desenvolvimento em desktop para uso de terceiros. Por exemplo, em sites você precisa de uma plataforma de hospedagem(certo?), e como funciona para aplicações em Java?

Outra coisa, como funciona o banco de dados dentro do Java?

Comment: O mais importante é saber o que vem antes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java pode ser usada tanto para uma aplicação cliente, contendo a interface que o usuário vai utilizar nas suas tarefas, como numa aplicação servidor, recebendo pedidos HTTP e respondendo da forma com que deseja.

No primeiro caso, aplicação client-side, você pode fazer uso do framework Swing para montar as janelas da aplicação e programar os botões e o que mais deseja. E existem bibliotecas para fazer as mais variadas coisas em aplicativos GUI com Java, como a [JFreeCharts](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) que permite plotar gráficos na janela.

No segundo caso, como um servidor, você faria uso da API de HTTPRequests para formular, enviar, receber e processar pedidos HTML. Alguns frameworks ajudam bastante aqui, como [Spring](https://spring.io/) e [Primefaces](https://www.primefaces.org/), este focado na camada visual da aplicação. Existe também a possibilidade de usar a edição JEE, com recursos como Servlets para processamento e JSP para as páginas que serão usadas para receber dados do usuário (formulários).

No caso misto, que Java age tanto como um cliente como um servidor, você pode usar ambas as formas citadas acima, desde que a ligação entre elas seja feita.

Sobre bancos de dados, a conexão geralmente é feita por drivers e uma API, a JDBC (**J**ava **D**ata**B**ase **C**onnection). Existem frameworks para isso também, como o [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/).

Comment: Esclareceu bastante, obrigada!

Comment: Alguns pontos: JavaFX é mais atual que Swing. E antes do PrimeFaces aprenda JSF.